# Помогите выполнить синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Наоборот, все его боялись, так как здесь, в лесу, он, сам того не подозревая, был самым крупным и опасным зверем. Ему не страшны были ни волки, ни рыси, ни крошечные куницы - все те ужасные существа, от которых плохо приходится мелкому зверю и птице.

Comment: Мы не выполняем домашние задания. Предложите свой вариант, поделитесь сомнениями — и мы вам поможем.

Comment: В первом предложении основа предложения - ОН БЫЛ. Это простое, осложненное предложение, деепричастный оборот, уточн.сл.

Comment: А "все  боялись"? Разве это не еще одна основа?

Comment: Во втором предложении основа - ни волки, ни рыси, ни куницы были не страшны. Повеств., невоскл., распр., прост., ослож. однород. подлежащими.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы.

Comment: А что, по-вашему, такое "плохо приходится мелкому зверю и птице"?

Comment: Приходится - сказуемое, а что является подлежащим?

Comment: Похоже, тут нет подлежащего.

Comment: По-моему, сказуемое — "плохо приходится". Но подождите других ответов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

*Наоборот, все его боялись, так как здесь, в лесу, он, сам того не подозревая, был самым крупным и опасным зверем.* (повеств., невоскл., сложное, сложноподчинённое, состоит из 2 простых:1.-главное, двусоставное, распр., осложнено вводным словом; 2.-придаточное причины, двусоставное, рапр.,осложнено уточняющим обстоятельством и обособл. обстоят., выраженным дееприч. об.)1 предл. грамм. основа:все-подлежащее, боялись - прост.глаг. сказуемое; 2 предл.: он - подлеж., был зверем-сост.именное сказ.

*Ему не страшны были ни волки, ни рыси, ни крошечные куницы - все те ужасные существа, от которых плохо приходится мелкому зверю и птице.* - повеств., невоскл., сложное, сложноподч., сост. из 2 простых:

1- главное, двусост., распр., осл. однородными подлежащими с обобщающим сочетанием "все существа".(ни волки, ни рыси, ни крошечные куницы, все существа -подлежащие, не страшны- сказуемое).

2- придаточное определительное, односоставное безличное, распр., осложнено однородными дополнениями.(плохо приходится - сказуемое)